# Remove loading spinner when content is finished loading

Tags: android, facebook, listview

I have this imageview that is a custom "spinner" that rotates:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.call_activity);

    final ImageView z = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSpinner);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CallActivity.this, R.anim.spinner);
        z.startAnimation(anim);
```

And i have this listview:

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {

            // populate list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Profile profile : friends) {
                //profile.getInstalled();
                values.add(profile.getName());          
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_items2, values);
            friendsListAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                    return lhs.compareTo(rhs);    
                }
            });
```

The listview loads friends from facebook.
What i have so far is that the list loads, and the spinner still shows, how could i make it so that when the listview has loaded its content, the spinner disappears?

-------------EDIT-----------------

```
        mSpinner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSpinner);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CallActivity.this, R.anim.spinner);
        mSpinner.startAnimation(anim);
```

And:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                });
```

And:

```
private ImageView mSpinner;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your spinner into a member variable

```
private ImageView mSpinner;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mSpinner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSpinner);
    ...
}
```

and add the following inside your onComplete method

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSpinner.clearAnimation();
            mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is a constant on view. It should resolve it if you change it to View.GONE

Comment: anywhere you had been using z now use mSpinner

Comment: No errors now, but it keeps showing in the app even though the content is loaded

Comment: Does adding mSpinner.clearAnimation(); help? Im not really sure what you are saying your new issue is

Comment: The new issue is that when the listview is loaded, the spinner is still there spinning, i tried with clearAnimation but that only "freezes" the spinner

Comment: and you got rid of final ImageView z = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSpinner);? and you are sure you dont have a second spinner image in the layout xml?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Can you mark this answer accepted or add your own answer if you dont think it was this that solved it